# Kotlin Vertx Type Mismatch found Future<Unit> expected Handler<AsyncResult<Void>>

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, kotlin-interop

I thought that in Kotlin, `Unit` was equivalent to `Void`. With Vert.x Service Discovery, it is not possible to pass a `Future<Unit>` to `unpublish(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<Void>> resultHandler)` (gives a type mismatch) yet it will accept `Future<Void>` without any problem. Why is this and is there a solution or will I just have to live with using `Void`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Unit` is not equivalent to `Void`, it is equivalent to `void` in kotlin.

In java, `void` is a keyword, but `Void` is a class. so the code below can't be compiled:

```
fun foo():Void{/**need return a Void instance exactly**/}

fun bar():Void{ return Unit; }
//                     ^--- type mismatch error
```

java applies the same rule, for example:

```
Void canNotBeCompiled(){
  // must return a Void instance exactly.
}

Void foo(){
  return Void.TYPE;
}

Void nil(){
  return null;
}
```

Finally the [Unit](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/index.html) documentation also says:

> The type with only one value: the Unit object. This type corresponds to the **void** type in Java.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you're exactly right. Those pesky capital letters!

Comment: @amb85 Not at all.